# Javascript code to count occurrences of combination of elements of two different variables within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have a data that looks of the format

```
[
    {name: "a", class: "AA"},
    {name: "b", class: "BB"},
    {name: "xx", class: "XY"},
    {name: "a", class: "AA"},
    {name: "b", class: "BB"}
];
```

I am trying to reduce this to count the occurrences of combination of unique name and class value as follows

```
name:"a", class:"AA", count: 2,
name:"b", class: "BB", count: 2,
name:"xx", class:"XY", count:1
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript reducing elements of one variable is something I am familiar with but the combination of two different variable is where I need help. Sorry if this seems to basic for some of you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and optional `thisArg` parameter.

```js
var data = [{name:"a", class: "AA"}, {name:"b", class: "BB"}, {name:"xx", class: "XY"}, {name:"a", class:"AA"}, {name: "b", class:"BB"}];

var result = [];
data.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.name+'|'+e.class]) {
    this[e.name+'|'+e.class] = {name: e.name, class: e.class, count: 0}
    result.push(this[e.name+'|'+e.class]);
  }
  this[e.name+'|'+e.class].count++;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to iterate over the data array and concatenate the name and class properties of each object, then use that as a key for a counter object, incrementing the value of each key.

```
var data = [{name:"a", class: "AA"}, {name:"b", class: "BB"}, {name:"xx", class: "XY"}, {name:"a", class:"AA"}, {name: "b", class:"BB"}];
var counter = {};
for (let obj of data) {
    let key = `${obj.name}${obj.class}`;
    if (counter[key] === undefined) {
        counter[key] = 0;
    }
    counter[key]++;
}
console.log(counter);
```

Please keep in mind that the sample code uses features from [es6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```js
var input = [
    {name: "a", class: "AA"},
    {name: "b", class: "BB"},
    {name: "xx", class: "XY"},
    {name: "a", class: "AA"},
    {name: "b", class: "BB"}
];

var output = {};
input.forEach(function(element) {
  output[element.name] = output[element.name] || {};
  output[element.name][element.class] = output[element.name][element.class] || 0;
  ++output[element.name][element.class];
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your objects are all ordered like in your example you can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert them to a string. Use those strings as key for an object and use the object to count the appearances of each key.

Advantages: Works for every object, regardless of the properties

Disadvantages: You have to make sure the properties are all in the same order

Here's a JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jgn2matg/

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [] // your array here

data.reduce((result, value) => {
    const resultValue = result.find(resultItem => resultItem.name === value.name && resultItem.class === value.class); 

    resultValue ? resultValue.count++ : result.push(Object.assign(value, {count: 1}));

    return result;
}, []);
```